# How to list clients inside ng2-select in angular5?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular5, angular2-template

I would like to initialize my select with a variable called : listClient, which exists in component : project.component.ts. I'm using  ng2-select in angular5.

This is the file project.component.ts:

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {ProjetService} from '../../../../../service/projet.service';
import {Projet} from '../../Models/Projet';
import { ModalDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {ClientService} from '../../../../../service/client.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-projects',
  templateUrl: './projects.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./projects.component.scss']
})
export class ProjectsComponent implements OnInit {

listClients:any;

constructor(private router:Router,
              private projetSevice:ProjetService,
              private clientServ:ClientService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

 ngOnInit() {
       this.doSearch();
       this.clientList(); // to initialize the variable listClient i want to 
                             show in ng2-select
  }

clientList(){
    this.clientServ.getListClients()
      .subscribe((data:any)=>{
        this.listClients=data;
      },err=>{
        console.log('this is error ');
      })
  }

public selected(value:any):void {
    console.log('Selected value is: ', value);
  }

  public removed(value:any):void {
    console.log('Removed value is: ', value);
  }

  public typed(value:any):void {
    console.log('New search input: ', value);
  }

  public refreshValue(value:any):void {
    this.value = value;
  }



}
```

This is project.component.html:

```
<div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-5 col-form-label">To select a client : </label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">

        <ng-select [allowClear]="true"
                   [items]=""
                   (data)="refreshValue($event)"
                   (selected)="selected($event)"
                   (removed)="removed($event)"
                   (typed)="typed($event)"
                   placeholder="select a client"

        >
        </ng-select>


      </div>
    </div>
```

The variable listClient is like:

```
{
id : 1
firstname : "jack"
lastname  : "alterd"
....
```

}

I want to show only the firstname with lastname and then send the selected id to project.component.ts

I can't find any complete example on how to do that, any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are using this ng2-select: https://valor-software.com/ng2-select/.

The documentation states that the items collection must have an id property and a text property. From doc:

> items - (Array) - Array of items from which to select. Should be
>   an array of objects with id and text properties.

Since your listClient does not have those properties, I would recommend writing a getter in Typescript to return a mapped list that does.

Set the items property:

```html
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-5 col-form-label">To select a client : </label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">

    <ng-select *ngIf="_listClients"
               [allowClear]="true"
               [items]="listClient"
               (data)="refreshValue($event)"
               (selected)="selected($event)"
               (removed)="removed($event)"
               (typed)="typed($event)"
               placeholder="select a client">
    </ng-select>


  </div>
</div>
```

Map the values using a get in Typescript:

```js
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {ProjetService} from '../../../../../service/projet.service';
import {Projet} from '../../Models/Projet';
import { ModalDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {ClientService} from '../../../../../service/client.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-projects',
  templateUrl: './projects.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./projects.component.scss']
})
export class ProjectsComponent implements OnInit {

//create private instance
_listClients:any;

constructor(private router:Router,
              private projetSevice:ProjetService,
              private clientServ:ClientService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

 ngOnInit() {
       this.doSearch();
       this.clientList(); // to initialize the variable listClient i want to 
                          // show in ng2-select
  }
  //list client getter
  get listClient() {
    return this._listClients ? this._listClients.map(item => {
      return { id: item.id, text: (item.lastName + ', ' + item.firstName)}
    }) : [];
  }

clientList(){
    this.clientServ.getListClients()
      .subscribe((data:any)=>{
        //initialize the private instance
        this._listClients=data;
      },err=>{
        console.log('this is error ');
      })
  }

public selected(value:any):void {
    console.log('Selected value is: ', value);
  }

  public removed(value:any):void {
    console.log('Removed value is: ', value);
  }

  public typed(value:any):void {
    console.log('New search input: ', value);
  }

  public refreshValue(value:any):void {
    this.value = value;
  }



}
```

Comment: thank you for your help , before i'll try this , can you please tell me where are you using the getter listClient() ?

Comment: Yes, in the template when we set the [items] property. By saying listClient, we are using the get method which is defined as get listClient().

Comment: Ah okey this is clear now , i'll try this right now and tell you the result

Comment: i think there is a problem with map , i get this error : ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at ProjectsComponent.get [as listClient]

Comment: This sounds more like the data isn't available to the template at the time listClient is accessed. I edited my answer to include an *ngIf="listClient" so the element will not be rendered until data is available.

Comment: Added one more edit to make the _listClients public and use that to determine if data is available.

Comment: I also added a check to see if _listClients is null: return this._listClients ? this._listClients.map(item => {
          return { id: item.id, text: (item.lastName + ', ' + item.firstName)}
        }) : [];

Comment: for now there is no error , but the ng2-select is emty  , what do you think about that ?

Comment: I have created a small example that will load the options after 3 seconds here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ejtkkd

Comment: yeah i see , it's weired i did the same as in this exemple in my project but the ng select is always empty , i did a console.log(this._listClients) in  clientList() and everything is well (means no problem with backend ) ,

Comment: can you please tell me how can i test the result of get listClient() ?

Comment: Can you place it in an angular expression in your template somewhere on the page?
<div *ngFor="let item of listClient">
    {{item.text}}
</div>

Comment: back again , the <div> shows exactly the first name and lastename without any problem , i think i have a problem in ng2-select itself

Comment: Can you remove most of the events? Basically try to get it as minimal as possible similar to this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ejtkkd

Comment: so sad to tell you that , i have always the same problem , this is really weired

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170924/discussion-between-peter-and-des12zer).